# Magento product image not displaying in back-end as well as front-end

Tags: magento

I'm using latest **Community Edition of Magento 1.7.0.2** in my localhost(XAMPP-Server).
I'm facing the problem **while uploading a product image**. Images not showing up in back-end as well as front-end.

Any help ? thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: There is no Enterprise version 1.7.0.2.   That is a Community Edition version number.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the steps you've taken to add these pictures? Have you just dragged and dropped them into a directory or did you add them using your admin panel? Greets J.I.N.

Comment: Hi Klesis, thanks for your reply.                                     Yes i'm adding images through admin panel.System->Catalog->Manage Products left side using image tab for a product.

Comment: Yes its community edition. can you tell some solution to fix my issue.

Comment: I am facing similar problem with Magento 1.4.1.1 on localhost xampp, windows 7. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the cache, rebuild the indexes and make sure your media folder is writable.

Comment: Hi darin kolev thanks for your reply. Yes i already tried.  Here are things that I have tried that didn’t work:

- Erased the htaccess file from the “Media” folder
- Deleted and cleared the cache
- Rebuilt the indexes
- Made sure my “Media” folder was writeable
- Shrank the image to make sure it was below the correct file size limit
- Made sure my memory in PHP was set to 128MB.

Answer (score -1):

Rename .htaccess file to .htaccess-old in media directory of your Magento root.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This may solve the problem for your server. But other users read your answer too and try it out. What your answer lacks is the explanation why the renaming of the .htaccess file would solve the problem, hence the -1 rep.